# How to add an additional column with the filenames when merging many files?

Tags: r, list, merge, filenames

I am merging several files (more than 5000) to do some analysis. The script below will merge all these files, however, I do not know later which was the original file. What I would like to do is adding an additional column with the name of the file. Row names = TRUE only adds numbers, but I would like the exact name.

```
setwd("/path")
library(data.table)
temp2 = list.files(path= "path", pattern="*.txt")

myfiles2 = lapply(temp2, function(x)read.table(x, header=T, sep="\t", comment.char="#",na.strings=".",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,quote="",fill=FALSE))

merged_dataset <- data.table::rbindlist(myfiles2,fill=TRUE)

write.table(merged_dataset, file="merged_dataset.txt", sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

My output now:

```
chr     pos     ref     alt...  
1       1902906 T       G...
1       1904677 A       C...
2       1976878 C       G...
3       1908790 C       T...
1       1904566 T       A...
2       1966789 T       G...
```

what I would like:

```
chr     pos     ref     alt...  phenotype  
1       1902906 T       G...    filename.txt
1       1904677 A       C...    filename.txt
2       1976878 C       G...    filename.txt
3       1908790 C       T...    filename.txt
1       1904566 T       A...    filename2.txt
2       1966789 T       G...    filename2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
myfiles2 = lapply(temp2, function(x) data.frame(read.table(x, header=T, sep="\t", comment.char="#",na.strings=".",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,quote="",fill=FALSE), phenotype = x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but I'd try

```
myfiles2 = lapply(temp2, function(x){a<- read.table(x, header=T, sep="\t", comment.char="#",na.strings=".",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,quote="",fill=FALSE); a$phenotype <- x})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(temp2, ~ read_tsv(.x, comment = '#', na = ".", quote = "") %>%
        mutate(phenotype = .x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `data.table`, I suggest using `fread()` for the reading..
If you name the resulting list with the filenames you have already gathered, you can use these names in your final table, using the `idcol`-argument of the `data.table::rbindlist()`-function

```
library(data.table)

myfiles2 = lapply( temp2, data.table::fread, fill = TRUE) #optional improvement
names(myfiles2) <- basename(temp2)
data.table::rbindlist(myfiles2, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "phenotype")
```